# PC wakes up automatically only for a few minutes(I need more time)

Tags: windows-10

I set up Jenkins to run some jobs(It runs for 10 minutes) at night.

In that time, my PC had already went sleep. That's why i set up Task Scheduler to trigger it every day. Actions cmd.exe/c "exit".

This wakes up my PC only for two minutes, but I require it to run for 10 mins(and more in the future). Do you mind helping me solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you increase the time your PC takes to go to sleep? Or in task manager, adjust this task 'This task will prevent machine from sleeping' or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Open the control panel
 click on "Power Options"
 click on "Change plan settings"
 change sleep settings